# RecyclerView items not in center with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

i have a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` which load items like this:

[image]

as you can see there is a margin to left. I didn't add any sort of `ItemDecoration` to recyclerview and didn't add any margin to any of the layouts here.

i've already tried:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

and using `LinearSnapHelper` but none of them fixed it.

**item layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp">
            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/choosestorycoverimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/test"/>
            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/choosestorycoverimagelayer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/choosen_story_layer"/>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/choosestorynametext"

            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:text="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".ChooseStoryActivity">



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/choosestoryrecyclerview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**recyclerview adapter:**

```
public class ChooseStoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooseStoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "LibraryRecyclerViewAdap";
    private ArrayList<String> coverImageUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> nameTextList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<String> shelfNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<HashSet<String>> shelfStoryIDList = new ArrayList<>();

    private HashSet<String> shelfStoryIDSet = new HashSet<>();
    private Context context;

    public ChooseStoryRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> coverImageUrlList, ArrayList<String> nameTextList,Context context) {
        this.coverImageUrlList = coverImageUrlList;
        this.nameTextList = nameTextList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.choose_story_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    //***********the main method***********
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(coverImageUrlList.get(position))
                .into(holder.coverImage);
        holder.coverImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.coverImageLayer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    holder.coverImageLayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else{
                    holder.coverImageLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.nameText.setText(nameTextList.get(position));




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return coverImageUrlList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        RoundedImageView coverImage;
        TextView nameText;
        RoundedImageView coverImageLayer;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            coverImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.choosestorycoverimage);
            nameText =itemView.findViewById(R.id.choosestorynametext);
            coverImageLayer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.choosestorycoverimagelayer);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these unnecessary attributes from your recyclerView tag:

- android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
- android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

You should change the *width* of the parent RelativeLayout of your **item layout** to use **match_parent** instead of a fixed width and then play with the **spanCount** attribute of your *GridLayoutManager* if you want *smaller item layout*

You should also add the **GridLayoutManager** directly in your activity_main.xml if you don't really need any Custom GridLayoutManager.
For that, remove the GridLayoutManager from MainActivity.java if you have one and add these two new lines in your recyclerView tag

- app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
- app:spanCount="3"